# How can I make sure that JSF works?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat, jsf, sts

My JSF doesn't work, but it also doesn't give any errors.

I have a simple `index.xhtml` with `<h:outputText>` but it doesn't seem to work. Others like `<p>` work fine. It's only the JSF which doesn't work.

STS4 seems to deploy it using Tomcat 10.1.

I made a project with Spring Tool Suite 4, Spring Boot 3.2.3 version, JDK 17, and I have these:

pom.xml

[pom.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYRw8.png)

application.properties (under src/main/resources/)

```
# MySQL properties
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tuneles?serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=usuario
spring.datasource.password=akkodis

# Hibernate properties
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG
logging.level.jakarta.faces=DEBUG
```

faces-config.xml (under src/main/resources/META-INF/)

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee
                                  https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-facesconfig_3_0.xsd"
              version="3.0">

</faces-config>
```

I also tried adding the JoinFaces dependency, and eliminating the others related to JSF, since it supposedly installs everything needed, but JoinFaces only gave me errors.

I just need to have JSF working somehow.

Comment: Abovelinked duplicate gives you the minimal instructions. By the way, *"JoinFaces only gave me errors"*, you should never ignore errors as if they are for decoration only. Errors are the best search keywords you can get. Next time when you're unable to research/google an error, simply ask a question with the full error included. We are able to translate errors in layman's terms in order for you to be able to understand the real cause and meaning.